# MYSQL count multiple orders without grouping

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to produce a query that shows **every** order AND adds an additional column which shows if the customer has previously placed an order by NAME, ADDRESS or USER_ID, without grouping results.

I've tried:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`NAME`) c FROM `salesorders` GROUP BY `NAME` HAVING c > 0
```

This shows all customer orders, however if the customer has previously ordered before, the customers name only shows once due to the grouping.

e.g.

```
Name,        Date,       Previous_Orders
John Smith,  2019-11-28, 2
Lisa Thomas, 2019-11-20, 1
```

I would like it show both occurrences:

```
John Smith,  2019-11-28, 2
Lisa Thomas, 2019-11-20, 1
John Smith,  2019-05-07, 2
```

`salesorders` columns;

```
Name
User_ID
Date
```

Lets say the new column is `Previous_Orders`

Comment: You could make a self-join and group by an concatenated value consisting of name and date.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: 10.4.6-MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MariaDB 10.4.6 you can use `COUNT()` window function:

```
select *, 
  count(full_add) over (partition by full_add) Previous_Orders
from salesorders;
```

If the column `Name` is unique, then you can replace `user_id` with `Name` if you prefer.
If by `Previous_Orders` you mean the number of orders up to the date in the current row, then change to:

```
select *, 
  count(full_add) over (partition by full_add order by date) Previous_Orders
from salesorders;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=0128851e4312069c348ab137b7c11ad4).

Comment: Thank you forpas, I'm reading up on partition by, and would like to use it practically. Column `NAME` is not unique, only `ID`. I'm not sure how to explain this best, but ideally I would like to compare where ```NAME OR FULL_ADD OR USER_ID``` are the same. (using OR not AND)

Comment: If name is not unique then you **must** use user_id, otherwise you could get wrong results. As for FULL_ADD, what is it? I don't see it in the sample data.

Comment: The only unique column is ID. FULL_ADD is the customers address. Sorry for complicating matter, there are many other columns. These are the columns I would like to compare.

Comment: I'm not familiar with partition by, however I'm getting an error in phpMyAdmin for row 2. "An Alias was previously found near 'Previous_Orders'. For clarity, Previous_Orders should be an Alias of count.

Comment: When I asked if Name is unique I meant if every customer has a unique name. I suppose every customer has a unique user_id which you can use to perform the count and this is why I used it in my code. As for the error I can't tell how you use this code. For the sample data that you posted it should work without errors.

Comment: I've create a (very basic) fiddle with sample data. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5HwFEx5frBGwjS4GY49hqK/0

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d49a172ca8d9bd60b971ca348812a523

Comment: thats wonderful. At least you know what I need, even if I don't ;) I think your first example was correct.  Could you make an amendment; ON NAME = FULL_ADD OR NAME = USER_ID.

Comment: PAUL SMITH has 3 orders. Whilst there USER_ID has changed, there FULL_ADD (post code etc) is the same.

Comment: Can it be both? I can't see where an OR comparison can be inserted. I would like to compare NAME == FULL_ADD || NAME == USER_ID  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=036b830f073177aab0317bae2be5c3a8  The second example crashes, but should show PAUL SMITH with 3 orders.

Comment: Check the demo in my answer, it shows PAUL SMITH with 3 orders.

Comment: Thank you, it does now. In my last link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=036b830f073177aab0317bae2be5c3a8 Paul Smith has a new Post Code and doesn't detect the 3rd order. Hence why I would like to compare both FULL_ADD and USER_ID

Comment: You must a have a column that does not change. This is a rule and common practice in SQL. If all 3 columns that define the customer: name, address, user_id may change then you can't have a unique reference to a customer. You should only keep only 1 column in salesorders, like a customer's id that comes from the table customers. Otherwise you will face problems like this.

Comment: You're right, there needs to be a unique customer number. I'd prefer not to create another table collating user information. I should explain that since orders come from several marketplaces, often names, member identified/reference and addresses can be different.  'PAUL SMITH' may also use the alias 'JANE SMITH' or 'SMITH LTD'. For future knowledge, is it correct to say PARTITION BY is not compatible with AND / OR / ON comparative statements just as JOIN with ON/WHERE?

Comment: PARTITION BY can be used with multiple columns, like `PARTITION BY Name, Full_ADD` but this creates groups for each combination of Name and Full_ADD and this is **not** what you want. And also you can't do it with `PARTITION BY Name OR Full_ADD`. This would be syntactically correct only in Mysql but logically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join with the subquery for count group by name

```
SELECT s.*,  t.c 
FROM `salesorders`  s
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT name, COUNT(*) c
     FROM salesorders
     GROUP BY name) t ON t.name  = s.name 
WHERE t.c > 0
```

Comment: Thank you both. I've never tried self-joining before, so I'm not sure how the result will look. I may not have been clear on the columns, so I'll edit the question to reflect.

Comment: @jumpOnCommand  this is not a self join  ..  is a join with a subquery.. Once the subquery retunrn the aggregated  result you need  you can join with the main table.....anyway the simple way is try ..

Comment: What are the column headings for this example? I've been playing with it for 2 hours without success.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5HwFEx5frBGwjS4GY49hqK/1

Comment: answer updated ..  removed  wrong double FROM and add c alias